# Converting HTML to PDF with Fusion Charts on it

Tags: java, pdf, charts, phantomjs, fusioncharts

I am trying to convert HTML to PDF using phantomjs. I have charts on HTML that are rendered through Fusion Charts. But while exporting it to PDF line of the chart gets greyed out. Hence chart is not clear. I tried diabling animation, tooltip etc but no luck. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could add part of your code and the result image to clarify the situation.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to upload images. Please see here: http://temp-share.com/show/f3Y68pMun

Comment: While converting HTML to PDF, it is a known issue while using PhantomJS. It ignores the clipRect and captures the whole page.

Issue: <https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10465>

Answer (score 0):

A similiar feature has been used in one of the FusionCharts Dashboards. The link is http://www.fusioncharts.com/dashboards/twitter/ You can actually search for a hashtag and share the result page in social network ( which actually shares the screenshot of the result page). They are also using Phantom JS to capture the HTML page ( which contains FusionCharts ) as image. You can download the code also from the link above to solve your problem. Hope this helps.